# Need help to understand this assembly for fibonacci seq

Tags: assembly

I understand the assembly properly. I am just confused about variable 'b' and 'c'. It looks like b is stored at 12(%ebp). I conclude this from `cmp 12(%ebp), %eax`. If you look at func_8048516, it is adding -0x4(%ebp) which is 'i' and 12(%ebp) which is b. It should translate into `a=b+i` in the source code but it's `a=c+i`. Can anyone explain this?

[image: Assembly code]

[image: Source code]

Comment: What created the C/decompiled code? Are you sure that this is the result of the compilation?

Comment: @macro-controller this is a problem from picoCTF 2013. There might be a case of a small typo in the assembly from their side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiling this code in [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/ncPdKa) the c code assembles to mov 16(%ebp),%edx

which is variable c not b as in your screenshot

[image]